# What's wrong with this Python mock patch?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I'm having trouble mocking out the an imported module in a unit test. I'm trying to mock the PIL Image class in my module `tracker.models` using the mock module. I understand you are supposed to mock things where they are used, so I've written `@mock.patch('tracker.models.Image')` as my decorator for the unit test. I am trying to check whether the downloaded image gets opened as a PIL Image. The mock patch seems to be overwriting the entire Image module. Here is the error I'm getting when I run the test:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/tracker/models.py", line 40, in set_photo
    width, height = image.size
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Here's my unit test:

**test_models.py**

```
@responses.activate
@mock.patch('tracker.models.Image')
def test_set_photo(self, mock_pil_image):
    # Initialize data
    hammer = Product.objects.get(name="Hammer")
    fake_url = 'http://www.example.com/prod.jpeg'
    fake_destination = 'Hammer.jpeg'

    # Mock successful image download using sample image. (This works fine)
    with open('tracker/tests/test_data/small_pic.jpeg', 'r') as pic:
        sample_pic_content = pic.read()
    responses.add(responses.GET, fake_url, body=sample_pic_content, status=200, content_type='image/jpeg')

    # Run the actual method
    hammer.set_photo(fake_url, fake_destination)

    # Check that it was opened as a PIL Image
    self.assertTrue(mock_pil_image.open.called,
                    "Failed to open the downloaded file as a PIL image.")
```

Here is the piece of code it is testing.

**tracker/models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    def set_photo(self, url, filename):
        image_request_result = requests.get(url)
        image_request_result.content
        image = Image.open(StringIO(image_request_result.content))

        # Shrink photo if needed
        width, height = image.size  # Unit test fails here
        max_size = [MAX_IMAGE_SIZE, MAX_IMAGE_SIZE]
        if width > MAX_IMAGE_SIZE or height > MAX_IMAGE_SIZE:
            image.thumbnail(max_size)
        image_io = StringIO()
        image.save(image_io, format='JPEG')
        self.photo.save(filename, ContentFile(image_io.getvalue()))
```

Comment: `image.size` must be a tuple, but you didn't set any mock value for that tuple. So `image.size` returns a mock object instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How do I prevent my mock from overriding the default functionality? I want to selectively overwrite functions and check `.called` rather than do it wholesale for the whole module.

Comment: Why would you need that? You are not testing if the PIL module works, only if your code calls the right things and passes in the correct information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to configure the return value of `Image.open` to include a `size` attribute:

```
opened_image = mock_pil_image.open.return_value
opened_image.size = (42, 83)
```

Now when your function-under-test calls `Image.open` the returned `MagicMock` instance will have a `size` attribute that is a tuple.

You could do the same thing for any other methods or attributes that need to return something.

The `opened_image` reference is then also useful for testing other aspects of your function-under-test; you can now assert that `image.thumbnail` and `image.save` were called:

```
opened_image = mock_pil_image.open.return_value
opened_image.size = (42, 83)

# Run the actual method
hammer.set_photo(fake_url, fake_destination)

# Check that it was opened as a PIL Image
self.assertTrue(mock_pil_image.open.called,
                "Failed to open the downloaded file as a PIL image.")

self.assertTrue(opened_image.thumbnail.called)
self.assertTrue(opened_image.save.called)
```

This lets you test very accurately if your thumbnail size logic works correctly, for example, without having to test if PIL is doing what it does; PIL is not being tested here, after all.

Answer (score 0):

I was writing a similar test, but my function was using `Image.open` as a context manager (`with Image.open(<filepath>) as img:`). Thanks to Martijn Pieters' answer and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850070/ddg#28852060) I was able to get my test to work with:

```py
mock_pil_image.open.return_value.__enter__.return_value.size = (42, 83)
```