# How to mock a python library using patch in python regardless where it is used?

Tags: python, unit-testing, ftp, mocking, magicmock

In the following question the function that uses the ftplib is defined in the same file, which makes it trivial to patch ('ftplib.FTP')

[Mocking ftplib.FTP for unit testing Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817963/mocking-ftplib-ftp-for-unit-testing-python-code)

My question is: How should I proceed if, in my test, I would like to make an instance of a class (let's call it 'A') that uses the ftplib somewhere (ie: the class A has an instance of a class B and B has an FTP object which calls connect()) ?

```
import unittest
from mock import patch

class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):

  @patch(???)
  def test_1(self, mock_ftp_constructor):
      mock_ftp = mock_ftp_constructor.return_value
      a = A()
      self.assertTrue(mock_ftp.connect.called)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  unittest.main()
```

If I use the solution given in the other question, I find that the ftplib is called instead of the mock. How could I know the correct path of ftplib.FTP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with imports to mock a class, it matters the way how the file (where the class is) has imported the lib.

To make the patch it is necessary to know the **name** of the context where the lib is called.
If __name__ is `'A.B'`, patch would be: `@patch('A.B.ftplib.FTP')` if B imports FTP as `import ftplib`. 
If B imports the lib as `from ftplib import FTP`, it would be: `@patch('A.B.FTP')`

Comment: Hi what does this `A` and `B` stand for? Can I just use `@patch('ftplib.FTP_TLS')`? I've got a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66426586/how-to-mock-ftp-connection-with-ftps-tls-version-1-2Would be appreciated if you could take a look for me, thanks

Comment: `A` and `B` stands for packages inside the project. When you patch a path you actually patch the reference in the file. If you have a python package `A` that has a python package `B` and the code in `B` you are using the ftplib you have to mock that instead of the ftplib itself. Remember checking the builtin __name__ to know where are you standing at the moment of the call