# How to Write Mock Object for tempfile NamedTemporaryFile or a file like object

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

Below is my code : and need to test myfunction(). and how to create mock function of file.

```
def myfunction(self):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tf:
        f.seek(0)
        tf.write(f.read())
        tf.flush()
        ocr_content_dict = self.ocr.ocr_document(tf.name, mimetype) or ''
        ocr_content = ocr_content_dict['content']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Mocking a context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850070/python-mocking-a-context-manager)

Answer (score -2):

You can create a mock file object, or you could also use `BytesIO` / `StringIO`:

```
from io import BytesIO

class MockFileObject(object):
    '''
       write mock functions for any that are needed
       DONE: read
       TODO: write
       TODO: seek
       TODO: fileno
       TODO: flush
       TODO: name

       with context manangement use the dunder enter/exit
       TODO: __enter__
       TODO: __exit__

       ... etc
    '''

    def read(self):
        ''' example mock '''
        return BytesIO('some stuff').read()
```

Usage:

```
fo = MockFileObject()
with fo as f:
     print(f.read())
```

output:

```
some stuff
```

Comment: not able to understand, can you be more specific and expalin how to mock the file objext

Comment: @ChetanKabra all of the TODOs are functions that would need to be written in order to fully mock a file object. does this make sense?

Comment: ok got it but how to use this in mock_test. because I dont want to mock the tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() context manager and  f.read() function calls another function which return file