# Mocking urllib.request.urlopen's read function returns MagicMock signature

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm trying to mock out urllib.request.urlopen's Read method on Python 3:

**Function Code:**

```
try:
    with request.urlopen(_webhook_url, json.dumps(_message).encode('utf-8')) as _response:
        _response_body = _response.read()
        return _response_body
```

**Test Code:**

```
with mock.patch('urllib.request.urlopen') as mock_urlopen:
    response_mock = MagicMock()
    response_mock.read.return_value = 'ok'
    mock_urlopen.return_value = response_mock


    with self.stubber:
        _response = NotifySlack.lambda_handler(_event)

        self.assertEqual('ok', _response)
```

If I call `response_mock.read()` I get the 'ok' value returned, however when I assert the return value I get a mock signature:

```
Expected :ok
Actual   :<MagicMock name='urlopen().__enter__().read()' id='2148156925992'>
```

Any ideas on why the mock isn't returning the value assigned to read()?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28850070/3001761

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To follow @jonrsharpe's comment and the [Python: Mocking a context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28850070/3001761) thread, to properly *mock the context manager* in this case, you would need this interestingly looking line:

```
mock_urlopen.return_value.__enter__.return_value.read.return_value = 'ok'
#^^^^^^context manager to return response^^^^^^^|^^^read method^^^
```

Comment: That works, thanks! For other Python newbies (myself included), this particular approach seems to be required because I used the with keyword (which creates the context manager construct referred to in the answer). Had the been "_response = request.urlopen..." the original code would appear to have worked.

Comment: Also mentioned in the `unittest.mock` docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mocking-magic-methods

Comment: You can also do `mock_urlopen().__enter__().read.return_value = 'ok'`, which is shorter. If you are tracking whether your mock has been called then you can reset the call count with `mock_urlopen.reset_mock()`.