# How do I test a function called inside the tarfile.open context manager?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, tar

I've written a function that creates a tarball.

```py
# tarball.py
import os
import tarfile


def create_tarball():
    with tarfile.open("path/to/tar/file", "w:gz") as tar:
        tar.add(
            "/path/to/included/directory",
            arcname=os.path.basename("/path/to/included/directory"),
        )
```

I've written a passing test with an assertion on the `tarfile.open` context manager.

```py
from unittest.mock import patch

from tarball import create_tarball


@patch("tarball.tarfile.open")
def test_create_tarball_partial(mock_open):
    create_tarball()

    mock_open.assert_called_with("path/to/tar/file", "w:gz")
```

How do I write a test for a function called inside the `tarfile.open` context manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write a test for the `tar.add` function, do the following.

1. Patch the `os.path.basename` function
2. Create a mock of `tar.add` using [MagicMock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.MagicMock)
3. Set the value of the `tar.add` function inside the context manager to the MagicMock¹
4. Set the return value of the `os.path.basename` function
5. Assert on the mocked `os.path.basename` and `tarfile.open` functions

**For example:**

```py
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

from tarball import create_tarball


@patch("tarball.os.path.basename")
@patch("tarball.tarfile.open")
def test_create_tarball_full(mock_open, mock_basename):
    mock_add = MagicMock()
    mock_open.return_value.__enter__.return_value.add = mock_add
    mock_basename.return_value = "/path/to/included/directory"

    create_tarball()

    mock_open.assert_called_with("path/to/tar/file", "w:gz")
    mock_basename.assert_called_with("/path/to/included/directory")
    mock_add.assert_called_with(
        "/path/to/included/directory", arcname="/path/to/included/directory"
    )
```

---

¹[Python: Mocking a context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28852060/11809808)