# Test Multiprocessing Implementation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pytest

I was able to test the implementation without multiprocessing using the code below.

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

def side_effect_cube(x):
    return x**3

@patch("test.data.geocode.test_geo_thread.cube", side_effect=side_effect_cube)
def test_sum(mock_cube):
    assert find_cube(7) == [1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216]
    assert mock_cube.called

def find_cube(num):
    result = []
    for i in range(1,num):
        result.append(cube(i))
    return result

def cube(x):
    return x**3
```

However when I added multi-processing to the implementation , it started failing.

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import multiprocessing as mp

def side_effect_cube(x):
    return x**3

@patch("test.data.geocode.test_geo_thread.cube", side_effect=side_effect_cube)
def test_sum(mock_cube):
    assert find_cube(7) == [1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216]
    assert mock_cube.called

def find_cube(num):
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
    result = [pool.apply(cube, args=(x,)) for x in range(1, num)]
    return result

def cube(x):
    return x**3
```

Below is the error that I see

```
cls = <class 'multiprocessing.reduction.ForkingPickler'>, obj = (0, 0, <MagicMock name='cube' id='61482936'>, (1,), {}), protocol = None

    @classmethod
    def dumps(cls, obj, protocol=None):
        buf = io.BytesIO()
>       cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj) E       _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'unittest.mock.MagicMock'>: it's not the same object as unittest.mock.MagicMock

    ..\..\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py:51: PicklingError
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a **unresolved** problem.

"Because the class for any individual Mock / MagicMock isn't available at the
top level of the mock module I don't think this can be fixed (fundamental
pickle limitation)." [#139](https://github.com/testing-cabal/mock/issues/139)

Here some workarounds:
If you don't need the magic methods, like `assert` and `return_value` you can create a custom class, based on the issue referenced above, [#139](https://github.com/testing-cabal/mock/issues/139):

```
class PickableMock(Mock):
def __reduce__(self):
    return Mock, ()
```

---

As stated [here](https://github.com/lmaraite/Collaborative_Filtering/pull/24), you can use a [fork](https://github.com/uqfoundation/multiprocess) of the multiprocess lib, I recommended to check the [thread](https://github.com/lmaraite/Collaborative_Filtering/pull/24) to see the problems you may face with that.

---

The solution I used for my use case was to mock the `multiprocess.Pool()`, I used as a context manager, and thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850070/python-mocking-a-context-manager) I was able to mock and assert the method that was called with the correct arguments. Your code will be like:

```
import multiprocessing
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock


def cube(x):
    return x**3


def find_cube(num):
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as executor:
        return [executor.apply(cube, args=(x,)) for x in range(1, num)]


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("multiprocessing.Pool")
    def test_cube(self, pool):
        pool.return_value.__enter__.apply = MagicMock()
        num = 7
        find_cube(num)
        for i in range(1, num):
            self.assertEqual(i, 
pool.return_value.__enter__.mock_calls[i].kwargs['args'][0])
```