# How to mock sqlalchemy execution output inside `with` context manager

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I'm trying to write unit tests for my python script which uses `sqlalchemy` to connect to MySQL.

My function looks like this:

```py
def check_if_table_exists(db):
    with db.connect() as cursor:
        table_exists = cursor.execute(f"SHOW TABLES LIKE '{PRIMARY_TABLE_NAME}';")
        if not table_exists.rowcount:
            cursor.execute(f"CREATE TABLE...
```

I can't find any resources on how to first mock out `db.connect()`, which in turn also needs to have its `execute` mocked so that I can test different `table_exists` scenarios. It's also possible that my code is simply not cohesive to proper unit testing and I need to call the function with a cursor object to begin with.

For reference, `db` is the output of `sqlalchemy.create_engine`.

**TLDR I need help getting started on unit testing for cases where I get rows back for the `SHOW` statement and when I don't.**

Comment: For mocking a context manager check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28852060/12480730).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To patch a context manager, you have to patch the return value of `__enter__`, which is called on entering a context manager. Here is an example for your code:

```py
from unittest import mock
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from my_project.db_connect import check_if_table_exists


@mock.patch('sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.connect')
def test_dbconnect(engine_mock):
    db = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
    cursor_mock = engine_mock.return_value.__enter__.return_value
    cursor_mock.execute.return_value.rowcount = 0
    check_if_table_exists(db)
    cursor_mock.execute.assert_called_with("CREATE TABLE")
```

In this code `engine_mock.return_value` is a mocked instance of `Engine`, and to get the mock for `cursor`, you need to add `__enter__.return_value` as described.

Having this, you can now mock the return value of `execute` - in this case you are only interested in the `rowcount` attribute which is checked in the code. Note that this will change the return value for all calls of `execute` - if you need different values for subsequent calls, you can use `side_effect` instead.

Comment: i prefer the `with mock.patch("sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.connect") as engine_mock:` syntax but otherwise this worked like a charm, thanks!