# Mocking a custom context manager within a function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, contextmanager

I have a custom context manager defined as:

```py
# ~/db/query.py

@contextmanager
def get_db_connection(conn_string, **kwargs):
    try:
        conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string, **kwargs)
        yield conn
    except Exception as connection_error:
        raise ValueError('Could not connect to db.', connection_error) from None
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

Within a function called `get_data`, I pass the result of the context manager, `conn`, as an argument to another function, `get_data_for_id`:

```py
# ~/pkg/main.py

def get_data(ids):
    dfs = []
    with query.get_db_connection(conn_string) as conn:
        for id in ids:
            df = get_data_for_id(conn, id)
            dfs.append(df)
    return dfs
```

I want to test to make sure `get_data_for_id` is being called with specific arguments when I call `get_data`:

```py
# ~/pkg/test.py

@patch('db.query.get_db_connection')
@patch('main.get_data_for_id')
def test_get_data(self, mock_query, mock_conn):
    ids = [1, 2, 3]
    main.get_data(ids)
    self.assertEqual(mock_query.call_args_list, [call(mock_conn, x) for x in ids])
```

Now for some reason, `conn` returned from `query.get_db_connection` in main.py is a connection object when I expect it to be a `Mock()` object because I patched it. I am getting the following errors:

```
FAIL: test_get_data (__main__.Tests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\scrollout\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 1325, in patched
    return func(*newargs, **newkeywargs)
  File "\pkg\test.py", line 108, in test_get_data
    self.assertEqual(mock_query.call_args_list, [call(mock_conn, x) for x in ids])
AssertionError: [call(<pyodbc.Connection object at 0x000000000FC[126 chars], 3)] != [call(<MagicMock name='get_db_connection' id='26[133 chars], 3)]
```

Since `mock_conn` is already a `Mock()` object, other solutions on stack overflow that point out solutions by changing the context manager's `.return_value` don't apply.

How can I make both `conn` objects the same `Mock()`?

Comment: You are importing `query` in `main` with something like `from db import query`, so you have to patch this instance of `query`, e.g. `@patch('main.query.get_db_connection')` - see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6).

Comment: The context manager is now being called with arguments:
```[call(<MagicMock name='get_db_connection().__enter__()' id='261880080'>, 1),
 call(<MagicMock name='get_db_connection().__enter__()' id='261880080'>, 2),...]```

Comment: I had to use `mock_conn.return_value.__enter__.return_value` in addition to your solution

Comment: Right, you [always have to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850070/python-mocking-a-context-manager) to access a context manager, forgot to mention this.