# Testing ContextManager, Callable and MagicMock

Tags: python, pytest, magicmock

I'm attempting to write a unit test using MagicMock.

I have 2 classes that are being tested:

```py
class HelperClass:
    @property
    def output(self) -> dict[str, Any]:
        return self._output

    def __enter__(self):
        print("__enter__")
        self._output: dict[str, Any] = {}
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        print("__exit__")


class ImportantClass:
    def fn(self, key: str):
        with self._fac() as hc:
            if key not in hc.output:
                raise RuntimeError("bad bad not good")

            return hc.output[key]

    def __init__(self, fac: Callable[[], HelperClass]):
        self._fac = fac
```

`ImportantClass` is initialized with a factory method that can be used to create instances of `HelperClass`. Here's the test code

```py
def test_important_class():
    hc = MagicMock(spec=HelperClass)
    omock = PropertyMock(return_value={"foo": "bar", "baz": "quux"})
    type(hc).output = omock

    assert hc.output["foo"] == "bar"
    assert hc.output["baz"] == "quux" # these assertions succeed

    assert OuterClass(fac=lambda: hc).fn("foo") == "bar"
    assert OuterClass(fac=lambda: hc).fn("baz") == "quux" # these don't
```

When I run through the code in the debugger the type of `hc.output` while in the test is `dict[str: str]`, but when I step into the `fn` method, the type of `hc.output` is `MagicMock`.

---

**Update**
I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850070/python-mocking-a-context-manager) which shows that the issue I'm facing is related to the implicit `ContextManager` that is being created when calling `with self._fac() as hc`.

I'm still having a tough time updating the test, so that the `ContextManager` gets mocked appropriately.

Comment: Actually, only one class is under test,  - `HelperClass` never gets created or called as it's being mocked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it, I had to create a method that could be patched in the unit test

```
def get_mtc(self) -> MyTestClass: # this is a dummy method that will get patched
    return MyTestClass()


def test_test_class():
    patcher = patch("my_unit_tests.get_mtc")
    fty = patcher.start()
    fty.return_value.__enter__.return_value.output = {"foo": "bar", "baz": "quux"} # mocks the implicit ContextManager

    assert OuterClass(fty).fn("foo") == "bar"
    assert OuterClass(fty).fn("baz") == "quux"
    patcher.stop()
```

I'd be very interested to learn a more pythonic way of doing all of this.